# Core Plot Bar Chart Columns

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-plot

Is it possible to set some padding between the first bar and the Y axis?
The last bar is always a few pixels away from the right margin of the plot but the first column always appears cut by the Y axis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust the xRange of your plot space. Decrease the starting location and increase the length.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't need to increase the lenght of the xRange. I've just set a new starting location to a bit lower and it worked